# Incorrect URL printed in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have a blade file which has below reference

```
@include('Js/login')
```

In this above file, I have below code

```
<script>
    var processingImageUrl = '<img src="'+ "{!! URL('Images/ajax-loader.gif') !!}" + '" />'
</script>
```

When I checked the page source, it was like below.

```
var processingImageUrl = '<img src="' + "{!! URL('Images/ajax-loader.gif') !!}" + '" />'
```

I am trying to show the app path but due to some reasons it is being printed incorrectly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The file where your `script` is added, the file name should be end with blade.php.

Comment: Thank you very much. post it as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: Hey glad I could help you. Posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its not compiled. The file where your script is added, the file name should end with blade.php. Exmaple - `testview.blade.php`

Comment: Upvoted you. Thank you for the great answer. Just banged on target.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct HTML of laravel for img tag

```
{{ HTML::image('Images/ajax-loader.gif') }}
```

or you can add direct path from assets

```
<img src="{{asset('assets/Images/ajax-loader.gif')}}">
```

it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

Make a js variable like this in your blade

```
var pagedefaults = {
    ajax_image: "{{ asset('/images/ajax-loader.gif') }}",
}
```

Use this in your js file

```
<img src=" + pagedefaults.ajax_image + ">
```